Uncanny Sounding Technically Correct Sentence
I came across quite an odd predicament. This type of situations seldom appear - and the sentence could just be restructured to avoid the whole issue altogether, but it got me thinking what the rules for these types of cases could be...

Consider the following sentences:

"You can submit any type of document - handwritten, as well as typed".
"This could be considered as a felony, as well as a misdemeanor".


The "as well as" portion works rather well in these cases to get the point across. Even if it's not by the book so-too-speak, at the very least, it doesn't sound too uncanny or unnatural.


Now this is where things get confusing:

Suppose we write a computer program which accepts a numerical representation of an integer. It then outputs the textual form of the number. For example, if we provided the program with the number 39, it would procure the output "thirty-nine".


The output could be displayed as such:
You provided 39. In plain English, the number provided is THIRTY-NINE.





How can we describe what a program such as this does? The following is excerpt of concern I came up with:

"...The program then displays the number in two forms - as spelled out text, as well as AS RECEIVED".

As you can see, the consecutive "as" has rendered the sentence awkward & odd.
Is there an actual rule for this type of situation? Have you ever come across an issue akin to mine?
The reason for the stubbornness to include "as received" is just due to the fact that sometimes a program might receive input not limited to the alphanumeric domain. For my case, I simply avoided the issue with a sentence restructure but I share this to hear your opinions, advice or anecdotes.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
